# When does PC allocate static char* inside of if block

Tags: c++, c, performance, memory-management, allocation

If I have

```
if (a)
{
    char a[10000]=AllElementsFromBufferA();
    DoSomethingWithA(a);
}
else if (b)
{
    char b[10000]=AllElementsFromBufferB();
    DoSOmethingWithB(b);
}
else if (c)
{
.
.
.
x 70;
```

When does PC allocate this? Will it allocate it even if it doesnt go here?
Since I have code with many if-s and else-s and performance is very important, so I don't know if I should allocate it dynamically or like this. Because, if this is draining so much memory that is bad too.

Thanks!

**Edit 1**
I have put some more realistic example

Comment: *"performance is very important"* If that's true you'll have to measure what's fastest (and whether those "allocations" have a significant effect on your runtime to begin with).

Comment: with compiler optimizations this code is a no-op, there is no need to allocate anything. Please come up with a more realistic example

Comment: There is no "static char*" here. There are automatic arrays, which you can't initialise like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compilers that I know of will allocate space for all block-scope variables at function entry, whether the branch is taken or not, at least for small variables (scalars, small arrays, etc.).  On most platforms, setting aside stack space is simply a matter of adjusting the stack pointer, which is a fairly cheap operation.  Additionally, I think a few ABIs mandate that you set aside some "scratch" space in addition to space for locals.

I wrote up the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  int foo = 0;
  scanf( "%d", &foo );

  if ( foo == 1 )
  {
    char a[10000] = "foo";
    printf( "a = %s\n", a );
  }
  else if ( foo == 2 )
  {
    char b[10000] = "bar";
    printf( "b = %s\n", b );
  }
  else
  {
    char c[10000] = "bletch";
    printf( "c = %s\n", c );
  }

  printf( "done\n" );

  return 0;
}
```

and compiled with with gcc (5.3.0, MinGW) as follows:

```
gcc -S alloc.c
```

which gives me the following machine code listing:

```
        .file   "alloc.c"
        .def    ___main;        .scl    2;      .type   32;     .endef
        .section .rdata,"dr"
LC0:
        .ascii "%d\0"
LC1:
        .ascii "a = %s\12\0"
LC2:
        .ascii "b = %s\12\0"
LC3:
        .ascii "c = %s\12\0"
LC4:
        .ascii "done\0"
        .text
        .globl  _main
        .def    _main;  .scl    2;      .type   32;     .endef
_main:
LFB10:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushl   %ebp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
        .cfi_offset 5, -8
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
        andl    $-16, %esp
        movl    $10032, %eax              // allocate stack space
        call    ___chkstk_ms              // with these three
        subl    %eax, %esp                // instructions
        call    ___main
        movl    $0, 10028(%esp)
        leal    10028(%esp), %eax
        movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
        movl    $LC0, (%esp)
        call    _scanf
        movl    10028(%esp), %eax
        cmpl    $1, %eax                 // if ( foo == 1 )
        jne     L2
        movl    $7303014, 28(%esp)       // a[] = "foo"
        leal    32(%esp), %eax
        movl    $9996, %edx
        movl    %edx, 8(%esp)
        movl    $0, 4(%esp)
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        call    _memset
        leal    28(%esp), %eax
        movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
        movl    $LC1, (%esp)
        call    _printf
        jmp     L3
L2:
        movl    10028(%esp), %eax
        cmpl    $2, %eax                 // else if ( foo == 2 )
        jne     L4
        movl    $7496034, 28(%esp)       // b[] = "bar"
        leal    32(%esp), %eax
        movl    $9996, %edx
        movl    %edx, 8(%esp)
        movl    $0, 4(%esp)
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        call    _memset
        leal    28(%esp), %eax
        movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
        movl    $LC2, (%esp)
        call    _printf
        jmp     L3
L4:                                        // else
        movl    $1952803938, 28(%esp)      // c[] = "bletch"
        movl    $26723, 32(%esp)
        leal    36(%esp), %eax
        movl    $9992, %edx
        movl    %edx, 8(%esp)
        movl    $0, 4(%esp)
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        call    _memset
        leal    28(%esp), %eax
        movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
        movl    $LC3, (%esp)
        call    _printf
L3:
        movl    $LC4, (%esp)
        call    _puts
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        .cfi_restore 5
        .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
LFE10:
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 5.3.0"
        .def    _scanf; .scl    2;      .type   32;     .endef
        .def    _memset;        .scl    2;      .type   32;     .endef
        .def    _printf;        .scl    2;      .type   32;     .endef
        .def    _puts;  .scl    2;      .type   32;     .endef
```

So, gcc did something fairly clever here.  First, it was able to determine that you would only have one of `a` or `b` or `c` active at any given time, so it didn't attempt to allocate space for all three.  Instead, it allocated enough space for one instance, plus some scratch space:

```
    movl    $10032, %eax
    call    ___chkstk_ms
    subl    %eax, %esp
```

I'm assuming `__chkstk_ms` determines whether enough stack space is available for that large a request and will throw an exception if there isn't.

It didn't attempt to *initialize* each instance unless that specific branch was taken:

```
movl    $7303014, 28(%esp) // a[] = "foo"

movl    $7496034, 28(%esp) // b[] = "bar"

movl    $1952803938, 28(%esp) // c[] = "bletch"
movl    $26723, 32(%esp)
```

Instead of setting aside space for the string literals `"foo"`, `"bar"`, and `"bletch"`, gcc used the `movw` and `movl` instructions to copy 2- and 4-byte integers whose bit patterns correspond with the sequence of ASCII characters for those strings.  IOW:

```
   7303014  = 0x006f6f66 == "\0oof"
   7496034  = 0x00726162 == "\0rab"
1952803938  = 0x74656c62 == "telb"
     26723  = 0x00006863 == "\0\0hc"
```

Remember that x86 is little-endian, so everything reads "backwards".

**Important**

This is the behavior of *one* version of *one* compiler on *one* platform - there's no reason to believe different compilers will behave the same way.  However, my experience leads me to think that most compilers will try to be smart about how the allocate space, especially for very large objects.